# Read and echo image file Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have a small png file called `small.png`. I expect the following Node.js code to be equivalent to a `cat` of the file. However, I am clearly reading something incorrectly, as the result is different, and redirecting output into a new file results in something that is not even recognizable as a PNG.

```sh
node -e 'console.log(require("fs").readFileSync("static/small.png", "utf8").toString())'
```

Or, expanded:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
console.log(fs.readFileSync("static/small.png").toString());
```

I suspected it could be an encoding issue, but "utf16le" seemed to look less like the original.

Comment: Debugging tips are also appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "cat" of an image? Do you want to print the unrecognizable characters in your shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary file can't be reproduced as a utf8 string, unless maybe if it happens to be a utf8 string in the first place.

[fs.createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) defaults to no encoding and can be piped to the stdout of the node process.

```
const stream = require("fs").createReadStream("small.png")
stream.pipe(process.stdout)
```

```
% cat small.png | sha256sum
065453ee61387cec8383a2337c488a3f65e709f52637efd5f97c1efe6c333f2b  -

% node -e 'st = require("fs").createReadStream("small.png"); st.pipe(process.stdout)' | sha256sum
065453ee61387cec8383a2337c488a3f65e709f52637efd5f97c1efe6c333f2b  -
```